# R session aborted when running dbscan

Tags: r, fatal-error, dbscan

I am trying to cluster a dataset which has 25 columns - 1 column with an id and 24 columns telling how many times an application with this id has been clicked for each hour of the day. When I try to run dbscan from the package dbscan the R session is aborted with a fatal error.

I tried to use dbscan on the same data, where it was group by day instead of hour and it works fine. Is there a limit on how many dimensions dbscan can handle?

Comment: The `dbscan` package seems to be pretty young. You can try the `fpc` package, if your data set is not very large. In my experiments, both were very slow compared to ELKI (but the `dbscan` package has been updated since). How many instances do you have?

Comment: The R session aborted probably is an error in the C code of the `dbscan` package. Please contact the authors for debugging assistance (but make sure to update to the latest version first).

Comment: Thanks! I have approximately 47 rows and 24 columns. Would that be concerned as a large data set for the `fpc` package? Sorry for my simple questions - I'm quite new in this R-world :) @Anony-Mousse

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, I tried using the `fpc` package instead and it works :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed an early bug which has been resolved in the current version. Here is some random data with 1000 points and 100 dimensions.

```
> library(dbscan)
> dat <- matrix(runif(100*1000), ncol=100)
> system.time(db <- dbscan(dat, eps = 3.2))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.272   0.000   0.264 
> db
  DBSCAN clustering for 1000 objects.
  Parameters: eps = 3.2, minPts = 5
  The clustering contains 2 cluster(s).
  Available fields: cluster, eps, minPts
```